# Ruby on Rails 6 - implementing javascripts (chess.js)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, chessboard.js

**Looking for help with application of custom javascript in Rails 6 framework.** I am trying to implement the small example coming from chess.js module (https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md) in my rails 6 newly set up app  (I am running the in ubuntu subsystem on windows) which should trigger a random game of chess in the console.

```
index.html.erb  

<script> 

  const chess = new Chess()

  while (!chess.game_over()) {
      const moves = chess.moves()
      const move = moves[Math.floor(Math.random()*moves.length)]
      chess.move(move)
  }
  console.log(chess.pgn())      

  </script>
```

My understanding is that Rails 6 uses webpacker for managing scripts like that and once I install the modules through npm and yarn I should be able to use the functionality without adding the chess.js file to the /app/javascript/ folder manually.

```
# NPM
npm install chess.js

# Yarn
yarn add chess.js
```

(I can see that chess.js have been added under config/node_modules/)

**When I run above snippet I get an error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

**and when I omit the first line in the above snippet then I get:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chess is not defined
```

I was trying also to place the chess.js in the  /app/javascript/packs folder and then load that through

```
import "chess.js"
require("channels")
require("packs/chess")
```

in the application.js, but it is all leaping in the dark with my little experience with the Rails framework.

**Would you please demonstrate correct implementation of this small example? Is it possible to implement this script in the Rails 6 framework?**

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "run this script in the Rails 6 framework". Rails does not run JavaScript, it compiles it into bundles to run in the browser.

Comment: @meagar sorry for the confusion and thanks for pointing that out, I have very limited experience with Ruby on Rails, by "run" I meant to implement the javascript. I updated the wording in my question. is the Ruby on Rails generally a good environment for implementation of third party javascripts or should I avoid that?

Comment: You can use absolutely any JavaScript you want with Rails, but again, It's Rails' job to pass it through to the front-end for execution.

Comment: @meagar I compiled the javasript though the webpack in the above example. what I am doing wrong here?